# Sum of large list or range goes beyond the scope

Tags: groovy

i was  playing with groovy and wrote simple one line program:

```
groovy -e "(1..100_000).each{println((1..it).sum())}"
```

the result was piped to file with '>'.

i got 2 main problems with that:

1. It takes too long time (i compared that with similar python script)
2. Output went beyond the scope and my sums turned negative afters some time

How could i accelerate execution and have longs or bigints in sum results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to determine the numbers in range as long not int:

```
groovy -e "(1..100_000).each{println((1..(it as long)).sum())}"
```

or with BigInteger:

```
groovy -e "(1..100_000).each{println((1..it).sum(0G))}"
```

still do not know about performance issue, if there is something i can do to accelerate this script.

Answer (score 1):

So, you've answered part 2 of your question. In terms of making it run faster, you can define your logic recursively and take advantage of [memoization](http://www.objectpartners.com/2014/01/28/memoization-in-groovy/).

```
groovy -e "@groovy.transform.Memoized c(BigInteger i) { i == 1 ? 1 : c(i - 1) + i }; (1..100_000).each { println c(it) }"
```

Comment: it, works but its not solution based on sum() function, i am curious why python's sum() is mutch faster, but your answer is nice and interesting:)

Comment: `sum()` performance was already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009708/groovy-collections-perfomance-considerations-regarding-space-time/24010258#24010258