# From a memory standpoint, are there any advantages or disadvantages of using .each{} to iterate over a collection in Groovy instead of a for loop?

Tags: groovy

Simple illustrative example :

Using .each{} on the collection :

```
def adults = Person.findAllByAgeGreaterThan(18)

adults.each{adult ->
    //perform action on adult
}
```

Using *for* to iterate over the collection :

```
def adults = Person.findAllByAgeGreaterThan(18)

for(adult in adults){
    //perform action on adult
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009708/groovy-collections-perfomance-considerations-regarding-space-time/24010258#24010258

Comment: you might as well waste a whole lot more memory by loading a huge result set there...

Comment: @Opal yeah sorry it is duplicate, just more specific, i couldn't find that post in my searches.

Comment: @cfrick note that it is a simple illustrative example.  try not to lose sleep over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop is slightly better: It doesn't have to create a `Closure` instance, for example. Details depend on your Groovy version, compiler and JIT optimizations and a few more things. If you need to know for sure, run the code through a memory profiler.

But since we're talking only a few dozen bytes here, you shouldn't feel the urge "I need to fix this code". It's probably just a waste of time (i.e. fixing it is more expensive than letting it be).

In 2014, [the first goal for code is readability](http://va.lent.in/optimize-for-readability-first/).

Only when the performance is really bad and you **measured** with a profiler **why** it's bad, it is time to fix the code (i.e. to sacrifice time, maintainability and readability for better performance).

Comment: Thanks.  I was mainly curious if there was anything within the semantics of closure scope that could cause drastic memory differences between the two.  From your answer it seems that is not the case.  I will accept this if nobody else feels the need to chime in.

Comment: A closure is an inner class which automatically makes any variable it references `final`. So it gets created once and then reused for the whole loop.

Comment: So would this mean the closure would make its own final copy of "adults" or any other variable in the closure scope and the memory usage for each variable would be doubled due to 2 instances of "adults" and other variables?

Comment: That depends on the implementation. But in Groovy, the code can actually modify the outer variable. For this, you just need to pass a reference which stays valid while the Closure exists. You don't have to copy the variable.