# Groovy: is sum() more efficient that calculating sum using inject?

Tags: groovy

Is doing `[1, 3, 5].sum()` significantly faster than `[1, 3, 5].inject( 0, {x, y -> x + y}`?

Comment: you should measure with your set of data on yourself (this is size of the list, the datatypes to sum up, things like @CompileStatic). and if you find, that in your case they really are for CPU and RAM equal, then i'd use `sum()` as the far more readable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the following benchmark:

```
@Grab(group='org.gperfutils', module='gbench', version='0.4.3-groovy-2.4')

def b = benchmark {
    'simple-sum' {
        [1, 3, 5].sum()
    }
    'inject-sum' {
        [1, 3, 5].inject(0, { x, y -> x + y })
    }
}
b.prettyPrint()
```

And the output:

```
Environment
===========
* Groovy: 2.4.0
* JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02, Oracle Corporation)
    * JRE: 1.8.0_05
    * Total Memory: 283.5 MB
    * Maximum Memory: 3641 MB
* OS: Mac OS X (10.10.1, x86_64)

Options
=======
* Warm Up: Auto (- 60 sec)
* CPU Time Measurement: On

            user  system  cpu  real

simple-sum   218       2  220   226
inject-sum   270       2  272   276
```

The output indicates that it's almost the same - `sum` is a bit faster in almost every attempt but the difference is not significant. Also have a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009708/groovy-collections-perfomance-considerations-regarding-space-time/24010258#24010258) how `sum` is implemented. In this simple case it might be faster however in more advanced scenarios the results can be inversed.

Comment: would you also say, that 20% off on your next car is insignificant ;)  changing the list into e.g. (0..10000) i get 35% better performance for the inject approach.

Comment: Heh, I wouldn't @cfrick :) I just meant that for basic cases/usages/sizes it's almost irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it yourself using closures:

```
def m1 = { l ->
    l.sum()
}

def m2 = { l ->
    l.inject( 0, {x, y -> x + y})
}


def benchmark = { l, c ->
     def d1 = new Date().time
     println "sum = ${c.call(l)}"
     def d2 = new Date().time
     println d2-d1
}

println benchmark([1,3,5], m1)
println benchmark([1,3,5], m2)
```

You would probably need to pass larger lists to have a better case.