# Groovy: Is for..in significantly faster than .each?

Tags: groovy, microbenchmark

I'm curious if `for..in` should be preferred to `.each` for performance reasons.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Note that JMH (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) has a groovy template which makes it easy (but not trivial) to create a Benchmark in groovy. Be sure to return with your findings!

Comment: @llogiq thanks for mentioning jmh! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: For me changing all `each` to `for-in` is probably the last on the list of optimization techniques. Just saying :-) Or to put it other way, one unnecessary DB call can equal to 1000s of  optimized `for-ins`.

Comment: Is this really the bottleneck in your application?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009708/groovy-collections-perfomance-considerations-regarding-space-time

Comment: Does it (really) matter?

Comment: @defectus I asked this out of curiosity. I'm learning stuff as a consequence :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`For .. in` is part of the standard language flow control.

Instead `each` calls a closure so with extra overhead.

`.each {...}` is syntax sugar equivalent to the method call `.each({...})`

Moreover, due to the fact that it is a closure, inside `each` code block you can't use `break` and `continue` statements to control the loop.

http://kunaldabir.blogspot.it/2011/07/groovy-performance-iterating-with.html

Updated benchmark Java 1.8.0_45 Groovy 2.4.3:

- 3327981  each {}
- 320949  for(){

Here is another benchmark with 100000 iterations:

```
lines = (1..100000)
// with list.each {}
start = System.nanoTime()
lines.each { line->
    line++;
}
println System.nanoTime() - start

// with loop over list
start = System.nanoTime()
for (line in lines){
    line++;
}
println System.nanoTime() - start
```

results:

- 261062715 each{}
- 64518703 for(){}

Comment: you are right but it's linked a gist, everyone can run the benchmark again.
I just do it with java8 and the result is: 3056480 / 8181870 / 3327981 / 320949

Comment: How long is the list?

Comment: the list size is 66 , quite short.

Comment: "inside each code block you can't use break and continue statements" - That is wrong. There is an issue of understanding the language and understanding why those don't do what some people think they do inside of the closure in that context, but it is perfectly legal and there are valid reason to use `break` and `continue` inside of a closure passed to the `each` method.  For example, if you had a loop or a switch statement inside of the closure.

Comment: Most often, when someone concludes that `break` and `continue` don't work there, that demonstrates a misunderstanding of what is happening when a closure is passed as an argument to the `each` method.  If you wrote a method that contained a `continue` and you invoked that method from inside of a loop, what would you expect that `continue` to mean?  That is similar to what is happening when `continue` is used inside of a closure that is passed to the `each` method.

Comment: Obviously I mean that is not possible to use break and continue to modify the loop with a closure as the inner code block like .each{}
Obviously in the closure we can create loops and use break and continue.

Comment: To be clear IMHO the fact that we can't use break and continue in loop with closure block code is very good.
It enforce the use of this constructs in the correct way: lambda calculus way.

Answer (score 5):

Let's have a theoretical look at things in terms of what calls are done dynamic and what calls are done more directly with Java logic (I will call those static calls).

In case of `for-in`, Groovy operates on an Iterator, to get it, we have one dynamic call to iterator(). If I am not mistaken, the hasNext and next calls are done using normal Java method call logic. Thus for each iteration we have here 2 static calls only. Depending on the benchmark it has to be noted that that first iterator() call can cause serious initialization times, since that may init the meta class system and that takes a moment.

In case of `each` we have the dynamic call to each itself, as well as the object creation for the open block (instance of Closure). each(Closure) will then call iterator() as well, but uncached... well all one-time cost. During the loop hasNext and next are done using Java logic that makes 2 static calls. The call into Closure instance is done with java standard logic for the method call, which then will invoke doCall using a dynamic call.

To sum it up, per iteration `for-in` uses only 2 static calls, while `each` has 3 static and 1 dynamic call. The dynamic call is much slower than multiple static calls and much more difficult to optimize for the JVM, thus dominating the timing. As a result of this `each` should always be slower, as long as the open block requires the dynamic call.

Because of the complicated logic for Closure#call it is difficult to optimize the dynamic call away. And that is annoying, because it is not really needed and will be removed as soon as we find a workaround. Should we ever succeed in that, `each` might still be slower, but it is a much more difficult thing, since bytecode sizes and invocation profiles play a role here. In theory they could be equal then (ignoring the init time), but the JVM has much more work to do. Of course the same applies for for examples stream based lambda processing in Java8,

Comment: In Java8 forEach with closure seems fastest than standard for loop.
https://gist.github.com/frhack/5db0485f9847e6b673be

Comment: @frhack you have to be careful with microbenchmarks like that. you have to give it a proper warmup time and best is to test only one construct at the same time. I am positive the times in both are very similar if tested with those constraints.  But there are of course differences in code size. The forEach version has the for-each method plus the lambda that has to be optimized. The normal for-loop version has the loop body, but also the method the loop body is in to optimize.  Which is why it is not good to have the loop plain in the test with everything else.

Comment: It results in a big codesize for the part to optimize and can bring the compiler to not to do that. In the end the forEach does the same logic steps as the normal loop, but with more method calls in between. So it takes longer to optimize... but in the end both should be equal. Everything else would mean wasted potential to me. There is for me no technical reason your example should behave all that different